# Can you run a bitcoin lightning node on a raspberry pi zero?

Tags: lightning-network, nodes, raspberry-pi, lightning-network-daemon

Will a bitcoin lightning node run on a raspberry pi zero? Does it have to have the full Bitcoin blockchain synced or can it connect to a remote node? Also what are the minimum requirements to get a lightning node up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will a bitcoin lightning node run on a raspberry pi zero?

This probably depends on what you are doing on the node, how much traffic it gets, etc. I have one running on a Raspberry Pi 3B with basically no traffic and its currently utilizing virtually no CPU and 0.8% memory.

> Does it have to have the full Bitcoin blockchain synced or can it
>   connect to a remote node?

No, it can connect to a remote node. For example, see https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning#getting-started.

> Also what are the minimum requirements to get a lightning node up?

I would recommend setting up C-Lighting, it currently works on Linux, and the dependencies are listed in the [Installation](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning#installation) section. You also need to fund a channel in order to be able to do any transactions.

Comment: What is C lightning and compared to what other alternative lightning?

Comment: It is one implementation of the lightning Network, specifically written in c. There is also one written in go: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd. Lightning Network isn't part of Bitcoin core, so these projects conform to the LN standards here: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc